# Floating point values with sin() and sinf()

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-accuracy, trigonometry

Why do I get the same value from sin(x) and sinf(x) as in (8) and (9) below? Why do I get different values of [ x - sinf(x) ] from two different implementations, (2) and (3) below? Why (6) gives the same result as (5)?

I am using g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3. I used -O0 to disable optimization.

Background: I was tracking down a bug in my program where I am required to use float throughout the program because it will be ported to an embedded system. However, I am currently debugging on Ubuntu on my PC just because it is convenient. I found the operation like (x-s) caused inaccuracy when x was small. That made me think it must be due to loss of significant digits by catastrophic cancellation. However, when I replaced a variable, s, with sinf(x), the problem of inaccuracy did not occur (as seen in (2) vs (3)). I could guess sinf() might be implemented as the same thing as sin(). If so, why does the explicit casting to float have no effect as in (4) and (5). Now I am puzzled.

```
int main()
{
    unsigned long int xx(0x3d65c2f2);
    float x(*reinterpret_cast<float*>(&xx));
    float s(sinf(x));

    printf("( 1) x                         = %.10e\n", x);
    printf("( 2) x - s                     = %.10e\n", x-s);
    printf("( 3) x - sinf(x)               = %.10e\n", x-sinf(x)); // Why is it different from (2)?
    printf("( 4) x - float(sinf(x))        = %.10e\n", x-float(sinf(x))); // Compare with (3). Why casting has no effect?
    printf("( 5) float(x) - float(sinf(x)) = %.10e\n", float(x)-float(sinf(x))); // Compare with (3). Why casting has no effect?
    printf("( 6) x - sin(x)                = %.10e\n", x - sin(x));

    printf("( 7) s                         = %.10e\n", s);
    printf("( 8) sinf(x)                   = %.10e\n", sinf(x));
    printf("( 9) sin(x)                    = %.10e\n", sin(x)); // Compare with (8). Is sinf() identical to sin()?
    printf("(10) float(sinf(x))            = %.10e\n", float(sinf(x))); // Compare with (8). Why casting has no effect?

    double s_df(sinf(x));
    double s_dd(sin(x));
    float s_fd(sin(x));
    float s_ff(sinf(x));
    printf("(20) s_df               = %.10e\n", s_df);
    printf("(21) s_dd               = %.10e\n", s_dd); // Compare with (20). Is sinf() identical to sin()?
    printf("(22) s_fd               = %.10e\n", s_fd);
    printf("(23) s_ff               = %.10e\n", s_ff);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
$ make && ./main
g++ main.cc -Wall  -c -o main.o -O0
g++ -o main main.o  
( 1) x                         = 5.6094117463e-02
( 2) x - s                     = 2.9411166906e-05
( 3) x - sinf(x)               = 2.9412529899e-05
( 4) x - float(sinf(x))        = 2.9412529899e-05
( 5) float(x) - float(sinf(x)) = 2.9412529899e-05
( 6) x - sin(x)                = 2.9412529899e-05
( 7) s                         = 5.6064706296e-02
( 8) sinf(x)                   = 5.6064704933e-02
( 9) sin(x)                    = 5.6064704933e-02
(10) float(sinf(x))            = 5.6064704933e-02
(20) s_df               = 5.6064704933e-02
(21) s_dd               = 5.6064704933e-02
(22) s_fd               = 5.6064706296e-02
(23) s_ff               = 5.6064706296e-02
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, `sin` has an overload `float sin(float f)`. And overload resolution is done on argument type, rather than return type. To force the use of `double sin(double d)` you need to cast the argument: `sin(static_cast<double>(x))`.

(2) vs (3): the FP standard allows implementations to store intermediate results with greater accuracy than the final result. So the value of `s` need not be exactly the same as the intermediate result for `sin(f)` in (3).

A lot of this is dependent on your compiler, compiler settings and hardware. For example, if I run your code on my system I get:

```
( 1) x                         = 5.6094117463e-02
( 2) x - s                     = 2.9411166906e-05
( 3) x - sinf(x)               = 2.9411166906e-05
( 4) x - float(sinf(x))        = 2.9411166906e-05
( 5) float(x) - float(sinf(x)) = 2.9411166906e-05
( 6) x - sin(x)                = 2.9412529899e-05
( 7) s                         = 5.6064706296e-02
( 8) sinf(x)                   = 5.6064706296e-02
( 9) sin(x)                    = 5.6064704933e-02
(10) float(sinf(x))            = 5.6064706296e-02
(20) s_df               = 5.6064706296e-02
(21) s_dd               = 5.6064704933e-02
(22) s_fd               = 5.6064706296e-02
(23) s_ff               = 5.6064706296e-02
```

Comment: Never recommend c-style casts! He should use `static_cast<double>(x)`

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: what other casts than `static_cast` do you think a C style cast to built-in numeric type can do? just to sum up my position on the general issue, never, absolutely never, recommend an absolute rule.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The use of `static_cast` here is not for the benefit of the compiler, rather it is for the benefit of some future reader. That reader now does not need to reason about how the C style cast will be interpreted. The point is to express the intent explicitly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the use of an ordinary C style cast would be for the benefit of the reader. you have completely misunderstood things. a competent reader seeing a `static_cast` will assume there's a *reason* for it, and there isn't, so it's a blind application of a general rule, yielding no advantage but time-wasting verbosity and time-wasting misdirection.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Clearly I am incompetent in that case

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: yes. of course, not in other matters. ;-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf If your target audience is intimately familiar with all the possible interpretations of different types of casts: sure. However, I personally don't believe in making that assumption on SO.

Comment: @Daan. Thanks for your reply. I did not know the intermediate results may be stored with more accuracy. However, does that mean even an explicit casting is ignored, as seen in (5) vs (6)?

Comment: @user22097 It might. A lot of this is implementation dependent. I get different results on my system, for example (edited into my answer, if you're curious).

Comment: @Daan. I appreciate that you pasted your result. Your result agrees with my understanding. Thanks for your replies.